# Want timestamp in CMD for every command

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, timestamp

So, I have opened a Windows CMD and I am running one build script command in it. Problem is, sometimes(honestly, often) I forget to run this build script after doing changes in my code. If there was something like timestamp along with the full path I can just look at the time the last command was run and instead of running the build script again I can determine that problem is with my code or because I didn't run a build script.

If CMD has something like this:

```
<timestamp><path><command>
```

That would solve the problem.

Any alternative for CMD like cmder or something would be fine too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the `%PROMPT%` variable has substitutions for current date and time. However, it shows the time the prompt itself was displayed (i.e. when the *previous* command *finished*), not the time the current command was run.

The default value is `$P$G` (path + greater-than sign). You can use `$T` for time and `$D` for date, [as well as several other expansions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/prompt).

```
set PROMPT=($T) $P$G
```

See also:

- https://ss64.com/nt/prompt.html
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/prompt
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028372/how-to-change-command-line-prompt-in-windows

Comment: Cool. That worked. Thank you :).

Comment: You should also add a setx command, because otherwise the prompt is restored to its default when you close the command prompt window. The syntax would be `Setx prompt %prompt%`

Comment: @LPChip or you can add variable in system/users variables in Windows to have it on every Windows start.

Comment: @dawciobiel of course. that is exactly what setx does. The difference is that when you setup your prompt, you are already in the command prompt, so it is far easier to put setx in there than to copy the text, find the settings in system properties and put it in there.